# Installing Latest Eclipse version : NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently trying to install the latest verison of eclipse and I encountered this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl$AuthorizationHandlerImpl.reauthorize(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl$ConnectionHandler.process(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:1674)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl.createInputStream(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createInputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1314)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.handleArchiveRedirection(SetupCoreUtil.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.configureResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.configureResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.createResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.SetupWizard.<init>(SetupWizard.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.SetupWizard.<init>(SetupWizard.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.Installer.<init>(Installer.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.run(InstallerApplication.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.start(InstallerApplication.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
```

Do you guys have any idea about what may go wrong ?

I already have JDK 11 installed btw.

Thanks in advance for every answer.

AceKing

P.S: Please find enclosed another screenshot of the installer.

[image: Screenshot of the following error]

Comment: You say you've JDK11 installed, but your Eclipse Installer screenshot shows that it is using JRE 1.8: "-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\..."

Comment: Eclipse bug [541465](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=541465) discusses this